# how to configurate nested object in Unity's inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create nested object in C# script in Unity and change the values in it.

Class of nested object

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Replica : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Text;
    public int Speed = 1;
    public int PersonaID = 0;
}
```

Class with nested object

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/DialogContainer", order = 1)]
public class DialogContainer : ScriptableObject {
    public Replica[] Replicas; // Here is nested object
    public Sprite[] Avatars;
}
```

And when I created the ScriptableObject I saw that:
[Photo of ScriptableObject interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtnq6.png)

Here I can only put an instance of the class there, but I cannot configure it.

But i want to change values right in inspector without creating and inserting object of class "Replica" like in InputManager where I can create one more obj in axis, open it and change values in inspector like that.
[Photo of interface I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N87bZ.png)

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1):

If u want configurate your class in inspector, that class must be **not derived** from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` and be with tag `[System.Serializable]` than u can serialize it in nested class without creating instance.

Replica:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Replica
{
    public string Text;
    public int Speed = 1;
    public int PersonaID = 0;
}
```

Dialog Container:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogContainer : MonoBehaviour{
    public List<Replica> Replicas;
    public Sprite[] Avatars;
}
```

Than I saw that:[Inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfU2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you make a [custom editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for `DialogContainer`, you can't do what you want to do.  If you have a parent `ScriptableObject` that contains a child list of `ScriptableObject`s, you can't edit each child's fields when you have the parent selected in your Project View.

You will have to edit each child `Replica` by selecting the `Replica` instance in the Project View.  Then the Inspector will let you edit that `Replica`.